# React-Bootstrap modal only take last item of map

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm a beginner in coding. I'm creating my graphic designer portfolio. I've put all the portfolio content (thumbnail, client name, description...) into an array called "portfolio" in a JSON file. Each item the array is a different project.
I display a galery of thumbnails, and when I click on a thumbnail, a modal opens with the project details.

I map on my "portfolio" array to display the galery, that works. But when I open the modal, it always display the last item of my array.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
      projectName: "",
      show: false
    };

    this.handleShow = () => {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    };

    this.handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ show: false });
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1cbaj5")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.portfolio
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
    
  render() {
    const {error, isLoaded, items} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Erreur : {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Chargement…</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div id="portfolio">
          <h2>Portfolio</h2>
          <ul className="portfolio-list">
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.client}>
                <div className="vignette">

                  <button onClick={() => this.handleShow()}>
                    <h4>{item.client}</h4>
                    <div className="filtre"></div>
                    <img src={item.vignette} alt={item.titre} />
                  </button>

                  <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                      <h3>{item.client}</h3>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                      <p>{item.description}</p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                  </Modal>

                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

I would like the modal to display the corresponding project details.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have only 1 modal and pass data dynamically on `item` click,

```
<ul className="portfolio-list">
    {items.map(item => (
    <li key={item.client}>
        <div className="vignette">
            <button onClick={()=> this.handleShow(item)}> //Pass complete item object here
                <h4>{item.client}</h4>
                <div className="filtre"></div>
                <img src={item.vignette} alt={item.titre} />
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
    ))}
    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}> //Only one modal
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <h3>{this.state.activeItem.client}</h3>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <p>{this.state.activeItem.description}</p>
        </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
</ul>
```

Now in your `handleShow` function you can set `item` to state,

```
this.handleShow = (item) => {
   this.setState({activeItem:item}, ()=> this.setState({ show: true }));
};
```

Use `callback` to show modal, which makes sure `activeItem` have latest clicked `item`.

Initial state,

```
this.state = {
   error: null,
   isLoaded: false,
   items: [],
   projectName: "",
   show: false,
   activeItem:'' //new added
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The **previous answer is great**. In functional components it is possible to create a function for handling both states and it works perfectly.

```
    export const TeamCollection = () => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const handleName = (name) => {
    setName(name);
    setModalShow(true);
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        {team_data.map((item) => (
          <Col key={item.id}>
            <div style={{ width: "175px" }}>
              <ImageContainer>
                <LinkContainer onClick={() => handleName(item.name)}>
                  <BackgroundImage
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${item.imageUrl})` }}
                  />
                </LinkContainer>
              </ImageContainer>
              <h4>{item.name}</h4>
              <p>{item.position}</p>
            </div>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
      <RouteModal
        data={name}
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default TeamCollection;
```